# ECS fargate capacity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have create a ECS cluster and will use fargate.Now i am trying to create a capacity provider for ECS cluster.

As per documents below is sample for creating ECS CapacityProvider

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider",
  "Properties" : {
      "AutoScalingGroupProvider" : AutoScalingGroupProvider,
      "Name" : String,
      "Tags" : [ Tag, ... ]
    }
}
```

Here in above template we have to provide autoscalling group. But if i create ASG group them have to create launch configuration and provide instance type etc.

But as per my understanding in fargate we don't have to create EC2.And above LC and ASG will create EC2.
I am confused now how to create capacity provider in ECS fargate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to create capacity provider in ECS fargate

You **don't create it**. It is automatically provided and managed by AWS. You just associate them with your cluster using [DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html)

Comment: @ So we just have to provide FARGATE or FARGATE_SPOT as  CapacityProviders while creating Fargate cluster ?

Comment: @AWS_Lernar Yes, that's correct.